# Spring JPA table relationship naming convention

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have to entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private Set<AvatarExecution> user_executions;
    ...
}
```

And the second one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_executions")
public class UserExecution {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

Database is postgres, and contains two tables:

```
users
user_executions
```

When I try to execute query, like: findAll on two tables I get the following error:

```
jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "users_user_executions" does not exist
```

How Spring/Hibernate naming strategy works? What should I do?
I just want that Spring Boot app will look up for

```
user_executions
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like there is a typo error, in `@OneToMany` you used the entity `AvatarExecution`, and in `@ManyToOne` is included in entity `UserExecution`.

Usually, in Java, we use the camelCase naming convention. I suggest changing the `user_executions` to `userExecutions` or `executions` (of the property/field in the class `UserExecution`, not table name) and using the `mappedBy` property in `@OneToMany` annotation.

You can check for [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) about using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` with `mappedBy`.